# Deserialize XML object in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I've got an XML object. And I want to deserialize it into a table using T-SQL.

```xml
<Params>
    <type = 1> 
        <value> 10 </value>
    </type>

    <type = 2> 
        <value> abc </value>
    </type>
</Params>
```

How can I store this data into a table like this: 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Your XML is not valid.

Comment: something wrong with your xml type = 1 is not valid xml tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your XML is not valid - but if you had something like this:

```
<Params>
    <type ID="1"> 
        <value> 10 </value>
    </type>
    <type ID="2"> 
        <value> abc </value>
    </type>
</Params>
```

then you could use this XQuery / SQL statement to get what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Params>
    <type ID="1"> 
        <value> 10 </value>
    </type>
    <type ID="2"> 
        <value> abc </value>
    </type>
</Params>'

SELECT
    Type = TypeNode.value('@ID', 'int'),
    NodeValue = TypeNode.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/Params/type') AS XTbl(TypeNode)
```

I'm not clear how/what the `id` column is supposed to be - care to explain?

Comment: It's a `row_number()`, I assume.