# Deserialize XML data object in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserialize XML object in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562635/deserialize-xml-object-in-t-sql)

I got an XML object, and i want to deserialize him into a table using T-SQL.

```
<Params>
    <paramtype type = '1'>
        <value> abc</value>
    </paramtype>

    <paramtype type = '2'>
        <value> 123</value>
    </paramtype>
</Params>
```

How can i store all this data into a table like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values like this

```
select  
    x.v.value('@type','int') as [type],
    x.v.value('.','varchar(50)') as [value]
from    
    @x.nodes('/Params/paramtype') x(v)
```

where `@x` is your XML object.

and insert them into a table with an identity for the ID (or use `row_number()` to generate one)