# Deserialize XML data into a table

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserialize XML data object in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563091/deserialize-xml-data-object-in-t-sql)

I've got this XML object:

```
<params>
    <item>
        <idtype>1</idtype>
        <name>dsf2</name>
        <value>2012-10-05 23:59:59</value>      
    </item>

    <item>
        <idtype>2</idtype>
        <name>msm1</name>
        <value>999</value>      
    </item>
</params>
```

How can i save value data into a table like this one:  
[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<params>
    <item>
        <idtype>1</idtype>
        <name>dsf2</name>
        <value>2012-10-05 23:59:59</value>      
    </item>

    <item>
        <idtype>2</idtype>
        <name>msm1</name>
        <value>999</value>      
    </item>
</params>'

INSERT INTO [TableName] ([idtype], [name], [value])
SELECT    
    [idtype] = TypeNode.value('(idtype)[1]', 'int'),
    [name] = TypeNode.value('(name)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
    [value] = TypeNode.value('(value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/params/item') AS XTbl(TypeNode)
```

BTW: I assume your table is defined following way:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName](
    [idtype] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```