# Deserialize from SqlXml to object

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have an int value stored in SQL Server as `xml` type, which is `SqlXml` when retrieved in C#

The value in database:

```
<int>1234</int>
```

How can I deserialize this value to an `int` with value `1234`?

Comment: See this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562635/deserialize-xml-object-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `SqlXml` object contains exactly what was mentioned in the question, you might want to use the following helper method. Should work for any type that has been serialized this way, even complex objects.

```
static T GetValue<T>(SqlXml sqlXml)
{
    T value;

    // using System.Xml;
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = sqlXml.CreateReader())
    {
        // using System.Xml.Serialization;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        value = (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Example case:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    writer.WriteRaw("<int>123</int>");
    writer.Flush();

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
    {
        SqlXml sqlXml = new SqlXml(reader);

        int value = GetValue<Int32>(sqlXml);

        Debug.Assert(123 == value);
    }
}
```